# Easy gnu make makefile rule to build of GCC executable from multiple source files

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to make a simple as possible make file that uses the math library (fmax below, the rest is C cruft for this examlpe):

easy.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  double x=atof(argv[1]);
  double y=atof(argv[2]);
  double z=fmax(x,y);
  printf("max(%f,%f)=%f\n",x,y,z);
  return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
CFLAGS=-g
LDFLAGS=-lm

easy : easy.c
```

However this creates a link error (missing fmax).  This is because make places the LDFLAGS first in the compile line:

```sh
 > make easy
cc -g  -lm  easy.c   -o easy
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccmN5G9c.o: in function `main':
/home/user/projects/easy/easy.c:8: undefined reference to `fmax'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: easy] Error 1
```

Of course, if I explicitly put the LDFLAGS at the end using an explicit rule, it works:

```
CFLAGS=-g
LDFLAGS=-lm

easy : easy.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

Of course, understanding the Makefile is not nearly so easy now.  Does anyone have a reason why the default rule does not put the link line at the end?  Or is there an "easy" make that does allow a newcomer to link a number of source files into one executable (no lingering .o files)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using `LDLIBS` not `LDFLAGS`.  `LDFLAGS` is for linker flags (such as `-L`).  `LDLIBS` is for linker libraries (such as `-lm`).

If you investigate the default rules (`make -pf/dev/null`) you'll find this one:

```
LINK.o = $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)

%: %.o
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

(Ignore `LOADLIBES` as that's a deprecated name).  Also see [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html#index-LDLIBS) for `LDLIBS` and `LDFLAGS`.